# Cast individual elements of a Tuple from double? to double

Tags: c#, tuples

I have this:

```
Tuple<double?, double?, double?, int, int, int> R1;
```

and need this:

```
Tuple<double, double, double, int, int, int> R1a;
```

The value of the nullable elements are never null. How can this be done?

Comment: what would be the value of first item if `double?` is null? or will that ever happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var R1a = new Tuple<double, double, double, int, int, int>
    (R1.Item1.Value, R1.Item2.Value, R1.Item3.Value, R1.Item4, R1.Item5, R1.Item6);
```

But only if you can be sure that the **3 doubles all have a value** or you get an **exception at runtime**

Alternatively, if you want to have **0** for null values, use `GetValueOrDefault()` instead of `Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of a `Nullable<T>`, which will return the value of the item, or the default value for the type if it is `null`:

```
var R1a = new Tuple<double, double, double, int, int, int>(
    R1.Item1.GetValueOrDefault(), R1.Item2.GetValueOrDefault(), 
    R1.Item3.GetValueOrDefault(), R1.Item4, R1.Item5, R1.Item6);
```

Comment: Downvoter please comment what is not useful about this so it can be improved.